# How to Play mp4 Media in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, media

I'm on windows phone project. On this project, I get the mp4 videos on my application by using my web service. I want to play this media on device like here;

http://www.windowsphone.com/tr-tr/store/app/goller-cepte/522e5324-15b1-4ef5-82a2-340aaa781087

You see the 7th picture. I want to play my media like there.

I made a structure to play media like this but i did not like that and it is not healthy choice to play media.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Video}">
            <MediaElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" AutoPlay="False" IsMuted="False" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="10,82,10,307" MediaOpened="VideoPlayerMediaOpened" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding video_baslik}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="67" Width="436"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,516,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding video_spot}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="170" Width="456"/>
            <Slider x:Name="MediaProgress" Margin="0,394,0,217" Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.1" ValueChanged="MediaProgressValueChanged"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ElapsedTime" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,468,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00:00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="30" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="RemainingTime" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,472,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00:00" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="30" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </Grid>
```

Can anyone help me to play media like the link 7th picture ?

Thank you too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think tey use the Media Player launcher. You just pass it your video URL and it takes care of everything else, including the UI. More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004(v=vs.105).aspx